# What does it mean "absorb or absorb onto"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I wonder if this article is similar to my question.

Double Trouble: Marine Plastic Debris Absorbs Toxic Pollutants
....Researchers from San Diego State University and Oregon State University deployed small pellets made from different types of plastics in San Diego Bay to simulate plastic debris in the marine environment.They analyzed changes in concentrations of toxic pollutants called PAHs in the plastic over time to investigate whether plastics leached or accumulated these contaminants... 
http://oceanbites.org/double-trouble-marine-plastic-debris-interacts-with-toxic-pollutants/

Does the plastic debris absorb chemicals in the ocean?

*** original question**
What does it mean "absorb or absorb onto(the debris)?
The speaker simply wanted to say, 
chemicals in the plastic debris attach to the debris in the water?

What I study is the chemical component or the toxicity of plastic debris to organisms. So I research the chemicals in the plastic debris either through manufacturing or that **absorb or absorb onto** the debris in the ocean.

Comment: The chemicals aren't *absorbing* anything - it's the other way around. You're talking about chemicals that ***are absorbed*** by ocean-borne debris.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean [adsorb](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/adsorb) instead?

> (Of a solid) hold (molecules of a gas or liquid or solute) as a thin film on the outside surface or on internal surfaces within the material:
>   "the dye is adsorbed on to the fibre"

If you don't then you should be talking about chemicals [absorbed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/absorb) **by** the debris, that is soaked into or taken up by the debris.

In the context of your usage, adsorb could be correct where absorb is wrong.